# Use emmet and Coda clips together with Tab trigger

Tags: tabs, coda, emmet

Today I was playing with Coda 2 as this is for the first time I'm using it after buying the IDE yesterday night. I've installed **emmet** on coda to speed up my workflow. At the same time I was trying to save some snippets in the **Coda clips**. Unfortunately the problem started here! When I'm pressing the TAB key to bring my clips snippets to the editor, emmet comes up with it's html contents. Like when I was trying to trigger hhtm (which is my doctype declaration in Coda 2), it comes up with `<hhtm></hhtm>`. There is only one solution to this which is to uncheck the "Expand abbreviation with TAB key" in emmet, but I want to use both! Is there any way to use both emmet and Coda clips together at the same time using the TAB key?

Answer (score 0):

No, it’s not possible, Coda does not provide such API.

As a workaround you can keep all your snippets (“clips” in Coda terms) in Emmet: http://docs.emmet.io/customization/snippets/

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is a seriously old question, but in case someone else looks for the answer: Keep "Expand abbreviation with TAB key" on in emmet and you can use 'ALT + TAB' to expand your coda snippets - you just need to remember which are which!